# How to query the devices which data has been updated for the last hour in Apache IoTDB?

Tags: apache-iotdb, iotdb

I currently use Version 1.1 of Apache IoTDB, and I need to find the recent data updated in the server. I wonder how to query the devices which data has been updated in the last hour in IoTDB? How should I write the query statement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this query statement in Apache IoTDB: `select count(s1) from root.db.** where time >= now() -1h and time < now() having count(s1) > 0 align by device`.